# How to set a 'real' field to accept an out-of-scale value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, fields

I have an SQL Server database and one particular field that is a `real`.  The program that feeds it was modified and is now sending a value too small to be considered a real.

Is there a setting for that field I can set that will keep the DB from erroring out when the value is received, and just use the default (0)?

Here is the actual error:

[image: SQL Error]

and here is the properties dialog of the field:

[image: SQL properties]

The VBA (using ADO) that actually loads the value into the recordset is

```
rst.fields(pointname) = CSng(rCell.Value)
```

The low range of CSng is 1.401298E-45, while the low range for an SQL real is 1.18E-38.
I've tested and it works at E-38 and errors out at E-39.

Comment: Are you sure it is the value that is the problem, and not the data type as composed in the application? Could you show the code that constructs and passes this real value? What is the actual value that is causing a problem?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Sure, I can show the code (tomorrow when I get back to work), but I've already tested it and it works fine until I shrink the number to a small enough number.  I didn't try to pin down the exact value, but it's very reproducible.

Comment: You either need to fix the table so that it accepts the range and scale of values you want, or you need to fix the code so that it doesn't produce values that you don't want.

Comment: Usually the value is greater than one, or just slightly smaller, the problem is when it's a virtual zero, but still existent out to many decimal places.  This question is about how to fix it from the database end, but I already plan to fix it on the software end, just don't have the time right now to implement that fix. Note that this app has worked fine for a long time, and still works until that number just gets too crazy small (like between 10^-30 to 10^-45).

Comment: So how exactly was the program changed, such that it now produces values that don't work? Honestly I believe the solution is fixing the app rather than hacking the database to allow you to delay fixing the app...

Comment: We switched from using Excel Solver to Matlab Spreadsheet LinkEX using the fmincon optimization function.  I plan on looking at the fmincon function in more depth to see if I can restrain the number of decimals it returns.  But besides being in a hurry to get this fixed at least temporarily, I'd like to make sure the database can handle stuff like this in the future.

Comment: I doubt any such option exists. The error is a TDS protocol error which means it is being rejected very early on before things like column properties would enter into it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, code and a little more testing edited in.

Comment: I'm not surprised it errors out beyond E-38. After all: `DECLARE @i REAL = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000009;` yields the very descriptive error message: `Msg 1007, Level 15, State 1 The number '...' is out of the range for numeric representation (maximum precision 38).` If you need to store more than 38 digits, you'll need to get creative. Otherwise, the fix is to fix the app so it stops sending more than 38 digits. That fix should be trivial.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes, it makes sense, and what I had assumed all along, I was just hoping that there was a setting for that field that could be modified to keep it from erroring out.

Comment: I don't think so, even if you bypass TDS somehow, you still have SQL Server trying to deal with > 38 digits, which it doesn't know how to do. I tried playing with an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger, but even there you would have to change the code to pass a string instead of a number, as SQL Server balks at a number before it tries to even do anything with it (e.g. cast it to a string or different precision/scale).

Comment: Ok, guess I'll have to work on the code end.  If you summarize everything in an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - Can you change the parameter datatype to `@float`? If so that will probably get rounded down to `0` when inserting to a `real` column.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I could probably do something along those lines, but since I have a lot of these fields I was looking to avoid making such wholesale changes.  I've found a Matlab solution to my issue to avoid the problem, so I'm ok.